# Why WORD to FO-based Header heavy missaligment

Tags: docx4j

I am trying to convert a DOCX file to PDF using FO-based PDF output. The converted PDF have mis-alignment in header/footer. We updated from 8.1.6 to 8.3.9, i tried some 8.2.x Version, all the same Problem. The missaligment is extremly heavy about factor 10, so the pdf is unsable...
In Version 8.1.6 it worked quite nice...
The error is already in the xml, when the custome render method in FORendererPdfA is called

how to reproduce can be found on github: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/550

Maybe anybody has a idea?